# Accessing members of an object

Tags: c++, juce

I'm using the JUCE framework and I currently have access to an object and I need to access some text which belongs to this object. When I'm watching I can see the text that I want

[image: Screenshot of my watch whilst debugging]

But when I try access it directly with sound.name.text or using the sound.getName() (which belongs to the SamplerSound class) I get the output `class “juce::SynthesiserSound” has no member “name”`

Comment: [Taking a look at the documentation](https://juce.com/doc/classSynthesiserSound), `juce::SynthesiserSound` does not have a public member named `name`. It may well be in there, but from the lack of a documented getter function it doesn't appear that you are allowed to touch it.

Comment: Can you show some code? The debugger image here shows that your `sound` variable is of type `juce::SamplerSound`, not `SynthesizerSound`, but in your text here you say you're trying to access it through a different variable named `sounds` (but maybe that's a typo). Without code, it's impossible to see what's really going on here.

Comment: @bgporter that was a typo, I'm trying to access it with sound

Comment: It's private, that's what the lock icon next to the field name means. You cannot access it outside the class without a getter.

Comment: You still need to post code to see what's going on. My guess from what you've posted is that `sound` is of the wrong type, and you either need to change that type or perform a `dynamic_cast` to coerce it into the correct one.